# I am creating my own version of ls in and I'm stuck with a segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, ls

here is the code that I made for `ls -l`  I created a time functions to get the date of creation of the files then there is `get_permission` to get all the permissions, then I put it  all of it together in a function called `my_ls_l` and it segfault just here

```
void get_time(char *str)
{
    str[16] = '\0';
    str = str + 4;
    mini_printf("%s",str);
}

void get_permission(struct stat stat )
{

    my_putchar((S_ISDIR(stat.st_mode)) ? 'd' :
             (S_ISBLK(stat.st_mode) ? 'b' :
             (S_ISCHR(stat.st_mode) ? 'c' : '-')));
    my_putchar((stat.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? 'r' : '-');
    my_putchar((stat.st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? 'w' : '-');
    my_putchar((stat.st_mode & S_IXUSR) ? 'x' : '-');
    my_putchar((stat.st_mode & S_IRGRP) ? 'r' : '-');
    my_putchar((stat.st_mode & S_IWGRP) ? 'w' : '-');
    my_putchar((stat.st_mode & S_IXGRP) ? 'x' : '-');
    my_putchar((stat.st_mode & S_IROTH) ? 'r' : '-');
    my_putchar((stat.st_mode & S_IWOTH) ? 'w' : '-');
    my_putchar((stat.st_mode & S_IXOTH) ? 'x' :
    (stat.st_mode & S_ISVTX) ? 'T' : '-');
}

int my_ls_l(void)
{
    struct dirent *entry;
    DIR *dir;
    struct stat stat;
    struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(stat.st_uid);
    struct group *grp = getgrgid(stat.st_gid);

    dir = opendir("./");
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (entry->d_name[0] != '.') {
            get_permission(stat);
            mini_printf("%s", entry->d_name);
            mini_printf("%s",stat.st_nlink);
            mini_printf("%s",entry->d_name_name);
            mini_printf("%s",grp->gr_name);
            mini_printf("%s",stat.st_size);
            get_time(ctime(&stat.st_mtime));
            mini_printf("\n");
        }
    }
    mini_printf("\n");
    closedir(dir);
}
int main(void) {
    my_ls_l();
    return (0);
}
```

I was trying here to do ls -l and it get the name of the files and then it segfaults and I don't understand why

Comment: According to documentation of `ctime`, `The returned value points to an internal array whose validity or value may be altered by any subsequent call to asctime or ctime.`. Key point being 'internal'. You have NO idea how big that array is and you most certainly should NOT be writing to it.

Comment: `struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(stat.st_uid);`... But at that point in the code the `stat` structure is uninitialized. The order in which you do things matter.

Comment: `stat` is uninitialized at *every* point in the code.

Comment: where is code for my_putchar and mini_printf?

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple problems in your code.
The most glaring one being, that you do neither populate your `stat` structure, nor initialize it, meaning that every property of that structure can have any possible value. (Which makes it useless).

What you'll want is the `stat` function (https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), something like this:

```
int my_ls_l(void)
{
    struct dirent *entry;
    DIR *dir;
    struct stat st;


    dir = opendir("./");
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (entry->d_name[0] != '.'
            && !stat(entry->d_name, &st)
        ) {
            struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(st.st_uid);
            struct group *grp = getgrgid(st.st_gid);
            get_permission(stat);
            mini_printf("%s", entry->d_name);
            mini_printf("%s",st.st_nlink);
            mini_printf("%s",entry->d_name_name);
            mini_printf("%s",grp->gr_name);
            mini_printf("%s",st.st_size);
            get_time(ctime(&st.st_mtime));
            mini_printf("\n");
        }
    }
    mini_printf("\n");
    closedir(dir);
}
```

Always check the return value of functions like that.
Also, it would be best to pass an absolute path to `stat`, but for starters, the relative path should do.

Another (potential) issue is your use of `ctime`.
You are writing to a buffer of unknown size, which can be overwritten at any given time.

When working with buffers like that, copy the contents to a buffer whose size you know and work with that.

Your gettime function could be optimized like this:

```
void get_time(char *str)
{
    mini_printf("%s",str + 4);
}
```

This works, because you are not manipulating the buffer but 'copying' it to the output stream, starting with the 4th character.
It is reasonable to assume that the string in the ctime buffer already is 0 terminated.

On another note: Run your code through a debugger. It will help you find errors much faster than we here on StackOverflow could ever do. And it will help you learn to help yourself much better than we can too.

Comment: okay thanks you I will try what you said